# Use the number in one cell to define another cell

Tags: numbers, cells

I have a cell whose entry is a variable integer.
I'd like to use this number to define another cell.
For example, if the number is 5, then I want Excel to automatically return the whatever's in cell E5; similarly, if the number is 100, I want Excel to return whatever's in cell E100.
How do I do this?

Comment: Update: now, how can I define a range of cells from two index numbers, eg E5:E6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDIRECT()

Assume you have variable number in cell "F3" and values in column "E"..

Write formula like - `=INDIRECT("E"&F3)`

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDIRECT("E" & C2)
C2 = 5
```

`INDIRECT` returns a value from a cell that is referenced using a string i.e.
`"E2"`, `"A1"`, etc.
The and sign("&") concatenates two strings together.